# Визуальное сравнение 2 массивов в php

Tags: data-structures, php, yii, визуализация

Привет всем! 
Задача, казалось бы, тривиальная, но для меня она оказалась сложноватой.

Давайте представим себе отчет за определенный диапазон дат. Я не заморачивался сильно, и у меня он представлен в виде ассоциативного массива. Список ключей массива всегда одинаковый, отличаются только их значения.

Существуют ли каке нибудь библиотечки для облегчения вывода на экран стоящих рядом таких массивов, и при этом чтобы создавался третий столбец, в котором отображалась разница в показателях?

В итоге должно получиться как здесь:
[image]
Желтым цветом обозначены значения из двух массивов, а красным - разница.

Я соорудил свой велосипед, но он не очень красив, в связи с чем и задал этот вопрос.

Так же интересует вопрос сравнения двух массивов с переменным набором ключей.

Рад выслушать любые размышления по теме :]

Comment: а что мешает одним запросом получить все необходимые данные для отчета?

Comment: а это здесь при чем? вопрос не о том, как построить отчет, а о том, как визуализировать 2 набора уже готовых данных

Comment: Тогда вопрос задан не правильно причем тут "визуальное сравнение"?

Это называется вывод.

Взять и вывести в табличном виде.

Comment: Мне нужно выводить в столбец, а не в строку)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то визуализацию можно организовать так: сначала получить список всех ключей, а потом работать с обоими массивами сразу.

```
$keys = array_keys($period1);
foreach($keys as $key) {
  $diff = $period2[$key] - $period1[$key];
  echo "{$key} | {@$period1[$key]} | {@$period2[$key]} | {$diff}";
}
```

Comment: Фух, значит Я не один такой :]

Скажите, а как быть в случае, когда у двух массивов разные наборы ключей? Причем, может быть так, что количество ключей в обоих массивах одинаково, но они разные)

Comment: Можно попробовать объединить ключи

    $keys = array_unique(array_merge($period1, $period2));

Тогда, в случае отсутствия какого-либо значения в одном из периодов, будет что-то вроде

    +--------------------+----+----+----+
    | Показатели         | П1 | П2 | Р  |
    +--------------------+----+----+----+
    | Убито гопников     |  4 |  0 | -4 |
    | Нанято киллеров    |  2 |  3 |  1 |
    | Забанено тупиц     |  0 |  2 |  2 |
    | Уничтожено троллей |  0 |  1 |  1 |
    +--------------------+----+----+----+

Comment: @tabby_cat, вот за это спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону этих функций:

[array_intersect](http://www.php.su/functions/?array-intersect)

[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос внимательно. мне нужно **визуализировать**

Comment: И? Выводите один массив, рядом второй массив, рядом результат array_diff/intersect.

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос

Comment: Только картинка к вопросу не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: С чего это?В вопросе ясно написано, что нужно выводить на экран, и рядом отображать разницу в значениях этих показателей.

Comment: Из вопроса до правки этого не следовало. А после правки я вообще не понимаю в чём вопрос заключается. Ну, взять и вывести таблицу, в чём именно сложность-то?

Comment: посмотрите историю изменений. До правки тоже было написано `что нужно выводить на экран, и рядом отображать разницу в значениях этих показателей.`

А в чем вопрос - там тоже написано